# Why would light take time to reach distance if space and time are relative?

Tags: spacetime

I've read that according to speacial theory of relativity, the time slows down for moving object. If we think light itself as moving object the time is zero for that. Also the theory says the space also shrinks as much as time shrinks...if we assume time shrinked to it's max which is 100 causing it to stall and don't increase any second... Does it imply that space also would shrink to 100? And if yes then does that mean I'm going to receive the singnal from the object 10 light years ahead just in a snap? As the distance shrinked to 100 percent so 0 and time too.

Answer (score 2):

The distance (and time) shrink from the viewpoint of the fast-moving object, but not from the viewpoint of a stationary observer.